# tempnam() not working on client server

Tags: php

I did a script, which has to load a file from a ftp-server then parses it. The code relies on tempname to store the temporarily store the ftp-file. On my developement server (with php  5.3.10), this works flawlessly, however on the client machine (with php 5.2.17) it does not and gives me:

```
Warning: ftp_rawlist() [function.ftp-rawlist]: Unable to create temporary file. Check permissions in temporary files directory.
```

Can someone give me a clue what i could do?
(I am a little weak on the possibiities of php)

I used this code:

```
define ("LOCALFILE",tempnam('/tmp', 'data-'));
define ("USER","myusername");
define ("PASS","mypassword");
define('SERVER', "ftpserver.com");
define ("DIR","/path/");

function getFTPFile(){

    // connect
    if(!($conn_id = @ftp_connect(SERVER))){
        Error::throwOne("Could not connect to ".SERVER);

    };
    // login 
    if(!($login_result = @ftp_login($conn_id, USER, PASS))){
        Error::throwOne("LOGIN INCORRECT! user:".USER." pass:".PASS);
    };
    // try to change the directory to somedir
    if (!ftp_chdir($conn_id, DIR)) {
        Error::throwOne("Couldn't change directory\n");
    }; 

    if(!($a = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, '-1t'))){
        Error::throwOne("Couldn't get ftp_rawlist\n");
    };

    $server_file=($a[0]);
    if (!ftp_get($conn_id, LOCALFILE, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
        Error::throwOne("Couldn't get file\n");
    };
    ftp_close($conn_id);    
};
```

Comment: Do you have access to write into the designated directory?

Comment: The error looks to me like system-generated and have nothing to do with your `tmpname`.  Internally, FTP stores the file in its own temp file in temp filename in standard temp directory up to the point when it's downloaded - then moves it to the location you specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue.
Since my hoster does not like the /tmp directory ( who would blame them )
i need to first set
    putenv('TMPDIR=/the tmp-dir my provider gave me');
which then works with tempname

Comment: although this question is rather old, could you mark your answer as "right answer" so that this question can be closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The error looks to me like system-generated and have nothing to do with your tmpname. Internally, FTP stores the file in its own temp file in temp filename in standard temp directory up to the point when it's downloaded - then moves it to the location you specified.

Try putting this code before your download code:

```
$tmpdir = sys_get_temp_dir();
echo "Temp dir: $tmpdir\n";
echo  is_writable($tmpdir) ? "Temp dir is writable" : "Temp dir is not writable";
```

This will tell you if you have permissions to write to the system temp dir.  I further suggest that you use this `$tmpdir` variable instead of hardcoding "/tmp" in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Tried yor code and get
    Temp dir: /tmp Temp dir is not writable


So it seems i have to contact my Webhost Administrator?

Comment: Well, i know now that I cannot write to the temp-dir.
I think I would need another way to write my ftp-data.

Comment: Yes, that should be your next step.

Comment: Of course, you can try using some other directory for your temp files, but that may not help with ftp...

Comment: cant i just create a file using chmod?

Comment: No, that won't work as the issue is with the directory where you're creating a file.  Unless ftp can be instructed to use another directory for temporary storage, you'll have to take it up with the sysadmin.

Comment: Ah i See... I changed the dir from /tmp to what my sysadmin gave me and now tempnam() works.<br> however ftp_rawlist still wants to use /tmp ...

Comment: Yes, that's because internally the system's temp directory is `/tmp` and FTP internally uses system `temp`.  You can try setting environment variables TMP and TEMP from PHP to what you received from your sysadmin and see whether that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this occurred on Windows Server 2016 - and it was because my %TEMP% environment variable pointed to a subdirectory that didn't exist for whatever reason.

It did point to the correct one when I ran it as Administrator, though.